# blender python increment an integer

Tags: python, integer, increment, blender

I'm pretty sure this has been answered, but I can't seem to locate it.
What I want is a python script for Blender that creates a custom tab that contains a button. When that button is pressed, it prints the value of an integer and increments it, so that when you press the button again, it shows an incremented value. Everything seems to work, except for the incremental part.

Here is the code I am using at the moment:

## ===

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,)
from bpy.types import (Panel, Operator, AddonPreferences, PropertyGroup,)

def main(context): 
    my_number += 1
    print(str(my_number))

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_number = IntProperty(
        name="Int property",
        description="This is an integer.",
        default = 1
        )

class AddOne(bpy.types.Operator):
    """This is an operator"""
    bl_idname = "op.add_one"
    bl_label = "Increment by 1"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CreatePanel(bpy.types.Panel):

    bl_label = "Render Setup Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "Increment by 1 Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("op.add_one")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddOne)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreatePanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddOne)  
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings) 
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CreatePanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

## ===

However, when I press the button 'Increment by 1', I get the following error:

"local variable 'my_number' referenced before assignment"

The point of this exercise is just to create an integer variable, store it, then increment it's value and print it out.

EDIT: I added the actual code, rather than an image of it.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `my_number` is defined in the class `MySettings` - it can only be accessed through that class, whether that is inside a method that is also part of the class (`self.my_number`) or directly as a property that is part of an instance of the class (`settings_instance.my_number`).

You need to find a place outside of the operator and panel to store persistent variables. Adding a [custom property](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) to the [object](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html) or [scene](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Scene.html) types are common options. As you are showing your panel in the node editor, maybe you will want to add it to the [material](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html) to keep it specific to a material, instead of global to the scene. You define these properties in the addons `register()` and remove them in `unregister()`.

```
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)
    
def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_settings
```

Then in your operator (or `main()` function) and your panel you can access the variable through the `context` paramater.

```
context.scene.my_settings.my_number += 1
```

Putting that together into your example, with a label to show the value -

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (IntProperty,)
from bpy.types import (Panel, Operator, AddonPreferences, PropertyGroup,)

def main(context):
    context.scene.my_settings.my_number += 1
    print(str(context.scene.my_settings.my_number))

class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_number: IntProperty(
        name="Int property",
        description="This is an integer.",
        default = 1
        )

class AddOne(Operator):
    """This is an operator"""
    bl_idname = "op.add_one"
    bl_label = "Increment by 1"

    def execute(self, context):
        main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}

class CreatePanel(Panel):

    bl_label = "Render Setup Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'NODE_EDITOR'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Increment by 1 Tab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object

        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("op.add_one")
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text='Value is: '+str(context.scene.my_settings.my_number))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddOne)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.register_class(CreatePanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_settings = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddOne)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MySettings)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CreatePanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_settings

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

You will find [blender.stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com) a better place to ask for blender specific python help.

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep in mind to go over to blender's stack exchange in future. This has been helpful.

Comment: code produces an error in Blender 3.1: `RuntimeError: Error: Registering panel class: 'OBJECT_PT_hello' has category 'Increment by 1 Tab'`

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie, that was written four years ago for blender 2.75. From 3.0 blender no longer supports adding categories to the tools panel, so you need to change region type from TOOLS to UI. You also need to change the way the property is defined in a class. Updated to run in blender 3.x now.

Comment: ah yeah sorry didn't check. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally this problem **"local variable 'my_number' referenced before assignment"** comes when you have **'my_number'** variable in code and you had not initialized that variable at top of your code or before using that variable do one thing .

Declare `my_number=0` and then do your calculation on my_number variable .

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware that I need to initialize the variable before I can use it. The problem is where? 

If I, for example, put 'my_number=0' in the  'def main(context):' code block, then the integer will always revert back to 0, then increment by 1. The value will always be 1 then and won't increment.

Should I declare 'my_number=0' somewhere else in the code?